# error with express and connect-redis on store option

Tags: node.js, session, express

```
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile)
    .set("views", __dirname + '/views')
    .use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

/*********************************************************************/
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: "3636"
    }),
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var userSession = req.session.userSession;

    if (!userSession) {
        userSession = req.session.userSession = '';
    }
    next();

});

/************************************************************************/
server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index2.html', {
        infoUser: req.session.userSession
    });
})

    .use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

console shows me :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'userSession' of undefined.

I'm sure this error is caused by 'RedisStore' object but i don't know why and i don't know how the fixed ?

Have I any mistakes?

help me please !!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `RedisStore` config. The port setting should be a number, like this:

```
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: "localhost",
        port: 3636
    }),
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

If that doesn't fix it you should also make sure 3636 is the correct port. Redis uses 6379 by default.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i changed the port number but it does not fixed my problem my console shows me the same thing.
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'userSession' of undefined.**